# Creating a mib for an Unknown alert (Trap type 1.3.6.1.4.1.17304.7.3.6.1)

Tags: snmp, mib

I am new to SNMP Mibs. I need help to create a mib file for the following trap coming through to CA Spectrum. The code snippet I added compiled successfully in Spectrum and still does not want to work.

See picture below.

[image: Spectrum. See picture below.]

Here is the raw data from the snippet.

```
Unknown alert received from device dmzsoaqaapl2 of type Host_Device. Device Time 64+03:10:00. (Trap type 1.3.6.1.4.1.17304.7.3.6.1) 
Trap var bind data: 
OID: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 Value: 554100000 
OID: 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 Value: 1.3.6.1.4.1.17304.7.3.1 
OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.17304.7.3.0 Value: ContractID: ContractID_Test | Policy: SNMP | HTTP Routing Latency: 5514s
```

Here is my code:

```
LAYER7-CUSTOM-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN


IMPORTS
        OBJECT-TYPE, MODULE-IDENTITY, NOTIFICATION-TYPE, Counter32, Integer32, enterprises FROM SNMPv2-SMI

        DisplayString FROM SNMPv2-TC;

customl7 MODULE-IDENTITY
      LAST-UPDATED "202011020000Z"
      ORGANIZATION "SHOPRITE"
      CONTACT-INFO
            "Armin Wentzel
             Programmer II
      DESCRIPTION
            "Custom Integration for Layer7 to Spectrum"
      REVISION "202011020000Z"
      DESCRIPTION
            "updates to module identity"
      ::= { enterprises 17304 }

serviceTable OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX       SEQUENCE OF ServiceEntry
      MAX-ACCESS   not-accessible
      STATUS       current
      DESCRIPTION 
            "A list of service entries"
      ::= { customl7 7 }
      

      
serviceEntry OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX        ServiceEntry
      MAX-ACCESS    not-accessible
      STATUS        current   
      DESCRIPTION
            "A list of service entries."
      INDEX { serviceDescription }
      ::= { serviceTable 3 }
      
      
      
ssgNotifications OBJECT IDENTIFIER 
      ::= { customl7 7 3 6 } 

       
ServiceEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
        serviceDescription              DisplayString
}

serviceDescription OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX         DisplayString
      MAX-ACCESS     read-only
      STATUS         current
      DESCRIPTION
            "Service Description"
      ::= { serviceEntry 0 }

usertrapdata OBJECT-TYPE
      SYNTAX    DisplayString
      MAX-ACCESS read-only
      STATUS     current
      DESCRIPTION
        "A user defined string"
      ::= { ssgNotifications 255 }

layer7Generic NOTIFICATION-TYPE
      OBJECTS { usertrapdata }
      STATUS current
      DESCRIPTION
        "Layer7 Generic Errors"
      ::= { ssgNotifications 1 }

END
```

Spectrum needs the mib to be able to parse the trap to an alert in Spectrum.

Comment: Unless you work for the vendor, you shouldn't need to write a MIB document for such but to chase the vendor for the right document(s). If you indeed work for the vendor, and don't have internal guidance on how to write an industrial MIB document from the right resources, I doubt Stack Overflow is the right place for such tutorials.

Comment: Hi, I do not work for the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a MIB for a Trap to be translated into a meaningful Spectrum event/alarm. It's indeed easier to do it with a MIB, but it's not 100% mandatory. The Spectrum documentation describes the process of creating support for an unknown trap. [Here](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/it-operations-management/spectrum/21-2/managing-network/event-configuration/alertmap-files.html) info on that process.

Comment: While the link provided may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.